# Troubles when using mblogit: Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:13: unexpected symbol 1: .~.+Hunting season ^

Tags: r, error-handling, regression, multinomial

I want to run a multinomial mixed model for my Msc thesis with hunting season as a random factor. I found that the mblogit function normally should be able to do the job, however, I got error.

Summary of the data

```
 Hunting method def     Sex       Age class Hunting season        group_d     Sexb    
 DD:1657            female: 867   0 :416    11_12:338      Duo        : 111   0:1090  
 HD: 300            male  :1090   1 :599    12_13:341      Family Pack: 162   1: 867  
                                  2 :388    13_14:433      Solo       :1684           
                                  3+:554    14_15:408                                 
                                            17_18:287                                 
                                            20_21:150
```

More specifically I am interested in wether there are difference in age structure between the different type of groups. There I want to run following model (and afterwards I want compare the estimated marginal means to quantify possible differences):

```
mblogit( formula = `Age class` ~ Sex*group_d,  random = ~ 1 |`Hunting season` , data = modeldata)
```

Unfortunately I get this error: Error in str2lang(x) : :1:13: unexpected symbol
1: .~.+Hunting season
^

I am not familiar at all with multinomial mixed model. I previously ran a normal without the random factor, which runs perfectly fine.

I did not found a solution yet, are there maybe other ways to run multinomial mixed models?

Comment: The problem is apparently the space in the variable name.  You've quoted it correctly, so there appears to be a bug in the function.  Another hint is that the function calls `str2lang`, implying that it is handling language objects as strings (bad).  Anyway, you can probably work around it by renaming your variable without spaces.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks, that solves the issue. Unfortunately, when running the model I get a next warning: Warning: Inner iterations did not coverge - nlminb message: false convergence (8). What does this exactly say?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.